# Mercurial 1.7.3 certificate error Windows

Tags: ssl, mercurial, https, certificate

I'm trying to clone my repo in Mercurial 1.7.3 on Windows and get the following error:

C:\Dev>hg clone https://dev.mydomain.com/repo
abort: dev.mydomain.com certificate error: certificate is for *.webfaction.com

Do I have to pay for a real SSL certificate to get this to work at all or is there some way I can force it to do the clone?  (I understand that this is not a good idea in general for security reasons.  I would just like to get the code checked out.)

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 7):

You should look at this: [CACertificates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates).

Mercurial just recently started verifying certificates.  You can create exceptions for self-signed certs.

Answer (score 7):

Simply put this in your mercurial configuration file:

```
[web]
cacerts =
```

Comment: And with that specified it gives the host fingerprint in a warning message like this:

warning: xxx.com certificate with fingerprint xx:yy:da:95:b9:d3:f1:10:4f:24:3d:85:d0:1b:40:8d:e0:53:c8:47 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)

I then added removed above workaround and instead added:

[hostfingerprints]
xxx.com = xx:yy:da:95:b9:d3:f1:10:4f:24:3d:85:d0:1b:40:8d:e0:53:c8:47

Comment: And with that specified it gives the host fingerprint in a warning message like this:

`
warning: xxx.com certificate with fingerprint xx:yy:da:95:b9:d3:f1:10:4f:24:3d:85:d0:1b:40:8d:e0:53:c8:47 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
`

I then added removed above workaround and instead added:

`
[hostfingerprints]
xxx.com = xx:yy:da:95:b9:d3:f1:10:4f:24:3d:85:d0:1b:40:8d:e0:53:c8:47
`